How to use controller methods when they have different types
In my project I have several controllers for different needs.
Basically, there is a main GUI and its controller opens 'child-GUIs'. Several child GUI can be opened.
So in order to keep things tidy, I store a set of information in a list to keep track of things.
    public class InterfaceInformation {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader;
        Stage interfaceStage;
        Scene interfaceScene;
        String name;
        boolean SetForRemoval;
    }
    
    [...]
        private Map<String, InterfaceInformation> InterfaceList = new HashMap<String, InterfaceInformation>();
    [...]

Every single 'child' controller implements an Interface.
Something like :
    public interface CtrlCommon {
         public void doCommonThing01();
    }
    
    public class MyController extends BaseApplicationElements implements CtrlCommon {
        public void doCommonThing01() {
        // Do something
        }
    }

So when the time comes to call all this method in every child GUI, I use the list and try to get the Controller from the FXML Loader. But i'm stuck with the call of doCommonThing01().
    for (Map.Entry<String, InterfaceInformation> elm : InterfaceList.entrySet()) {
        elm.getValue().getFxmlLoader().getController().<i_m_stuck_here>
    }

I know that every controller has the method as it implements the interface. But I can't get it to work.
I don't know if trying to use <T> or <?> would help (and how).
What would be the trick to solve this?

Just cast it? Or since getController() is generic, you should be able to do CtrlCommon controller = elm.getValue().getFxmlLoader().getController(); controller.doCommonThing01();. Or define a CtrlCommon getController() method in InterfaceCommon that returns fxmlLoader.getController(). Or probably many other ways.

Doesn't InterfaceInformation.getFxmlLoader().getController() return an object that implements CtrlCommon?

To Abra, Maybe. If it is the case, Eclipse can't see it. I'm inclined to say Eclipse(java) isn't bad on tracking things.
@Jame_D : That did it. While casting it with the Interface puzzle me. Even though I clearly understand that it's only what I need to use the method. It still feels like giving a screw from the car engine and tell the guy : "now you can drive".

Casting is a way to tell the compiler you know more than it does. It's a valid language feature to use when it's needed. The controller's type is potentially determined by the FXML file, so the Java compiler can never be completely sure of the controller's type. This means you have to rely on casting (or reflection) to fully use the  object returned by FXMLLoader::getController. The way that method defines its generics means the cast is usually implicit. But you can also use an explicit cast. And if the class/method was designed differently, there'd still be a cast used internally.

Simple answer, perform an explicit cast:
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
        MyClass.class.getResource(
                "my-ui.fxml"
        )
);

MyControllerType controller = (MyControllerType) loader.getController();

Why a cast is required
In a comment, Slaw explains why a cast is needed:

Casting is a way to tell the compiler you know more than it does. It's a valid language feature to use when it's needed.
The controller's type is potentially determined by the FXML file, so the Java compiler can never be completely sure of the controller's type.
This means you have to rely on casting (or reflection) to fully use the object returned by FXMLLoader::getController. The way that method defines its generics means the cast is usually implicit. But you can also use an explicit cast. And if the class/method was designed differently, there'd still be a cast used internally.

Some casting options
The parts of the solution outlined below that address the aspects of your question: "How to use controller methods when they have different types".
Given a registry designed like this:
record InterfaceRecord(
    FXMLLoader loader,
    Stage stage,
    Scene scene,
    String name
) {} 

private final Map<String, InterfaceRecord> interfaces = new HashMap<>();

public InterfaceRecord lookup(String interfaceName) {
    return interfaces.get(interfaceName);
}

To use it:
InterfaceRecord record = registry.lookup(name);

Example looking up a controller from a loader, it uses some method based Java generic types, to reduce the number of casts you need to do on usage:
public <T> T lookupController(String interfaceName) {
    return interfaces.get(interfaceName).loader().getController();
}

To use it, any of these will work (it is doing an implicit cast to the type of the assigned variable):
Decorator decorator = registry.lookupController(name);
CarController car = registry.lookupController("car");

You can also always do an explicit cast:
Object object = registry.lookup("power").loader().getController();
NuclearPowerPlant plant = (NuclearPowerPlant) object; 

And this is a newer java feature for instanceof casting:
Object controller = item.loader().getController();

if (controller instanceof Painted painted) {
    texts.add(new Label(", "));

    Text paintedText = new Text("painted " + painted.getPaint());
    paintedText.setFill(painted.getPaint());
    texts.add(paintedText);
}

In later java versions switch statements can also switch on the type of objects.
The above list is not comprehensive for all ways to handle different types of generic objects.

The following example goes beyond what was asked in the question, so studying the example is not necessary to understand the answer to the question.
Example in context
This is not a direct answer to your question; it demonstrates how you might implement your concept of "storing a set of information in a list to keep track of things."
The implementation uses two fairly common programming patterns, a registry pattern and a decorator pattern, and demonstrates their use.
In the process, it will perform multiple casts to provide access to typed objects stored in the registry and to provide typed access to decorators so that the appropriate methods can be called on the appropriate stored objects and decorators.
This is not designed as a generic JavaFX interface framework, though I guess you could use it as part of that.  The code is presented as a Java Object Oriented tutorial sample.
Many JavaFX applications will be better off following a different pattern and separating the UI code from application logic using an MVC design pattern, potentially using an IOC container to handle the registry if that is needed, rather than implementing a registry in application code.  However, the solution below is fairly light-weight and you may find the concepts useful in some cases.

InterfaceApp.java
I won't explain the design and operation of the code in detail, except for the casting stuff discussed above, but hopefully, you can understand it by reading and studying it.
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

record InterfaceRecord(
        FXMLLoader loader,
        Stage stage,
        Scene scene,
        String name
) {}

interface Decorator {
    Paint DEFAULT_PAINT = Color.BEIGE;
    void paint(Paint paint);
}

interface Painted {
    Paint getPaint();
}

interface Powered {
    PowerPlant getPowerPlant();
}

class CarController implements Decorator, Painted, Powered {
    private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Paint> paint = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(DEFAULT_PAINT);
    private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<PowerPlant> powerPlant;

    public CarController(PowerPlant powerPlant) {
        this.powerPlant = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(powerPlant);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Paint paint) {
        this.paint.set(paint != null ? paint : DEFAULT_PAINT);
    }

    @Override
    public Paint getPaint() {
        return paint.get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Paint> paintProperty() {
        return paint.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    @Override
    public PowerPlant getPowerPlant() {
        return powerPlant.get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<PowerPlant> powerPlantProperty() {
        return powerPlant.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }
}

class SubmarineController implements Decorator, Painted {
    private Paint paint = Color.BEIGE;

    @Override
    public void paint(Paint paint) {
        this.paint = paint != null ? paint : DEFAULT_PAINT;
    }

    @Override
    public Paint getPaint() {
        return paint;
    }
}

interface PowerPlant {}

class NuclearPowerPlant implements Decorator, Painted, PowerPlant {
    private Paint paint = Color.BLUE;

    @Override
    public void paint(Paint paint) {
        this.paint = paint != null ? paint : DEFAULT_PAINT;
    }

    @Override
    public Paint getPaint() {
        return paint;
    }
}

class InterfaceRegistry {
    private static final InterfaceRegistry instance = new InterfaceRegistry();

    private final Map<String, InterfaceRecord> interfaces = new HashMap<>();
    private final ObservableList<InterfaceRecord> interfaceList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    private InterfaceRegistry() {}

    public void register(InterfaceRecord interfaceRecord) {
        interfaces.put(
                interfaceRecord.name(),
                interfaceRecord
        );

        interfaceList.add(interfaceRecord);
    }

    public void deregister(String name) {
        interfaceList.remove(lookup(name));
        interfaces.remove(name);
    }

    public InterfaceRecord lookup(String interfaceName) {
        return interfaces.get(interfaceName);
    }

    public <T> T lookupController(String interfaceName) {
        return interfaces.get(interfaceName).loader().getController();
    }

    public ObservableList<InterfaceRecord> getInterfaces() {
        return interfaceList;
    }

    public static InterfaceRegistry getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}

class InterfaceLoader {
    public static InterfaceRecord load(
            String interfaceName, 
            Object controller
    ) throws IOException {
        InterfaceRegistry registry = InterfaceRegistry.getInstance();
        
        InterfaceRecord interfaceRecord = registry.lookup(interfaceName);
        if (interfaceRecord != null) {
            return interfaceRecord;
        }
        
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
                InterfaceRegistry.class.getResource(
                        interfaceName + ".fxml"
                )
        );
        loader.setController(controller);
        
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));
        
        registry.register(
                new InterfaceRecord(
                        loader,
                        stage,
                        stage.getScene(),
                        interfaceName
                )
        );
        
        return registry.lookup(interfaceName);
    }
}

class InterfaceCell extends ListCell<InterfaceRecord> {
    private final TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow();

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(InterfaceRecord item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            setGraphic(null);
            textFlow.getChildren().clear();
            return;
        }

        ObservableList<Node> texts = textFlow.getChildren();
        texts.add(new Label(item.name()));

        Object controller = item.loader().getController();

        if (controller instanceof Painted painted) {
            texts.add(new Label(", "));

            Text paintedText = new Text("painted " + painted.getPaint());
            paintedText.setFill(painted.getPaint());
            texts.add(paintedText);
        }

        if (controller instanceof Powered powered) {
            texts.add(new Label(", "));

            PowerPlant powerPlant = powered.getPowerPlant();
            Text poweredByText = new Text("powered by a " + powerPlant.getClass().getSimpleName());
            poweredByText.setFill(Color.ORANGE);
            texts.add(poweredByText);

            if (powerPlant instanceof Painted powerPlantPainted) {
                Text paintedText = new Text(" painted " + powerPlantPainted.getPaint());
                paintedText.setFill(powerPlantPainted.getPaint());

                texts.add(paintedText);
            }
        }

        setGraphic(textFlow);
    }
}

public class InterfaceAccessApp extends Application {
    private final InterfaceRegistry registry = InterfaceRegistry.getInstance();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        InterfaceLoader.load(
                "power",
                new NuclearPowerPlant()
        );

        InterfaceLoader.load(
                "car",
                new CarController(
                        registry.lookupController(
                                "power"
                        )
                )
        );

        InterfaceLoader.load(
                "submarine",
                new SubmarineController()
        );

        Decorator autobodyShop = registry.lookupController("car");
        autobodyShop.paint(Color.RED);

        Decorator submarinePen = registry.lookupController("submarine");
        submarinePen.paint(Color.GREEN);

        ListView<InterfaceRecord> interfaceView = new ListView<>(registry.getInterfaces());
        interfaceView.setCellFactory(param -> new InterfaceCell());
        interfaceView.setPrefSize(500, 100);

        Pane layout = new VBox(
                10,
                interfaceView
        );
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        layout.setStyle("-fx-base: azure");

        stage.setTitle("Interfaces");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();

        System.out.println("Interfaces " + registry.getInterfaces());
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        List<InterfaceRecord> interfacesToRemove = new ArrayList<>(
                registry.getInterfaces()
        );

        interfacesToRemove
                .forEach(i ->
                        registry.deregister(
                                i.name()
                        )
                );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        launch(args);
    }
}

Where each of the fxml files car.fxml, submarine.fxml and power.fxml are just empty UI files for this demo.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane/>


While this answer is a good one that will work including for other situations / configurations. @James_D did a nicely "tailored" answer to my problem. The James_D answer in the form of a comment doesn't require any supplementary code. "Just cast it" using the interface! I think the credit should go to James_D. And sorry James_D that I misspelled your nick (Stupid autocorrection) in previous comments.
